# How do you integrate Gaussian integral with contour integration method?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

How do you integrate $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$$ with contour integration method?

I do not even know how to setup the problem.

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: **As a start :**
Consider the contour integral
$$
\oint_C e^{i\pi z^2}\csc\pi z\ dz
$$
where $C$ is the two parallel lines passing through $x=\pm\dfrac12$, making an angle of $\dfrac\pi4$ with respect to the real axis, and closed with vertical lines at $x=\pm R$, where we will take the limit $R\to\infty$

Comment: @Tunk-Fey That is one of the ways to evaluate it using a parallelogram. But a rectangle can be used as well.

Comment: @RandomVariable I didn't know that. Anyway, I'm still learning contour and residue integral so could you refer me a book(s) for a beginner to learn those methods. I'm having trouble to understand how to choose the appropriate contour for a specific integral. Thanks.

Comment: @RandomVariable Thank you very much... $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 5):

Sine the integrand is an even function then we have

> $$ I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = {2}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx. $$

Making the change of variables $u=x^2$ the integral under consideration becomes

> $$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-u}}{\sqrt{u}} du.$$

So we can consider the complex integral

> $$ \int_{C}\frac{e^{-z}}{\sqrt{z}} dz $$

Now you need to choose the right contour, noting that we have $z=0$ as a branch point.