# Show that $\int_0 ^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(2bx)\ \mathrm dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}e^{-b^2}}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> My textbook says show that  $$\int_0 ^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(2bx)\
>  \mathrm dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}e^{-b^2}}{2}$$

Also, there is a hint. Integrate $f(z)=e^{-z^2}$ on rectangle given by  $|x|\leq R,0\leq y \leq b$
and also use integral $\int_{-\infty} ^\infty e^{-t^2}dt=\sqrt\pi$

Also, I am reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317249/gaussian-like-integral-int-0-infty-e-x2-cos-a-x-mathrmdx) question answered by Moli.

And observing that on the two vertical sides, the integral approaches zero as $R→∞$, you will deduce that

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty{e^{-x^2}\cos(ax)dx}=\sqrt{\pi}\cdot e^{-\frac{a^2}{4}}.$

Can you please explain how this equality is derived? Why vertical integrals approach $0$ and how from that follows equality.

Comment: On this site I found something [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266856/gaussian-integral-using-contour-integration-with-a-parallelogram-contour?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C73.3872) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459612/can-we-use-contour-integration-to-compute-the-fourier-transform-of-gaussian?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C62.5916) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509458/contour-integral-of-a-complex-gaussian) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884923/how-do-you-integrate-gaussian-integral-with-contour-integration-method), and more.

Comment: Did you actually try to follow the hint? What happens when you perform the contour integral over the boundary of the rectangle?

Comment: Can you show us your attempt so we can see where exactly you're stuck?